# Kiel oni tradukas « I’m fed up of »?

Tags: phrase-requests

Ĉu Esperanto havas bonan esprimon por traduki ekzemple:

> I’m fed up of eating sprouts every day.

Mi kredas ke en la franca oni povas diri ion kiel:

> J’en ai marre de manger des choux.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Why did you remove the French and English tags? I think there was more support for this proposal on the meta than counter-support so I wanted to start introducing it. http://meta.esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/92/tags-for-when-a-language-is-referenced

Comment: That proposal didn't get much support. There are two users supporting it, and two users contrary. [Tags are for the subject of the question](http://meta.esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/4/an-esperante-tag-for-questions-written-mostly-or-entirely-in-esperanto/6#comment24_6) and the subject of this question is neither English nor French.

Comment: @kiamlaluno The proposal has two positive votes and one positive comment. Your counter-proposal has no votes. I think that is a relatively high amount of support considering the community is only small. Of course the question is about English, it is asking for a translation of an English phrase.

Comment: That is the score, not the number of up-votes and down-votes. Click on the score, and you will see the number of up-votes and down-votes. That means there are two users who are contrary: me and the user who up-voted. Since users who agree with you up-vote your question, there are two users who agree with your idea.

Comment: Alright... Three users supports that idea, and two users are contrary.

Comment: Still, the proposal doesn't have so much consensus. I would rather ask a question asking if those tags would be considered meta tags.

Comment: @kiamlaluno That seems like enough support to me. However I will wait to see if it gets more support before trying again with these tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say: *Mi ne plu povas elteni (la) ĉiutagan manĝadon de...* ("I can no longer endure (the) everyday eating of..."). *Toleri* (to tolerate) might also be a good word. These seem to carry the tone of your original English sentence more than something like *enui* or *tediĝi* ("I am bored of/bothered by..." respectively).

I have never heard *... de x-i*, where *x-i* is an infinitive verb, that sound unnatural just like "I am bored of to eat sprouts everyday". To me, *Mi enuas pro tio, ke ni/mi manĝas bruselbrasikojn ĉiutage.* or *Mi ne plu povas toleri (tion), ke ni/mi manĝas bruselbrasikojn ĉiutage.* sounds much better.

---

REDAKTO: Mi tute ne rimarkis ke la demando estas en Esperanto... :P Jen traduko:

Mi dirus "Mi ne plu povas elteni (la) ĉiutagan manĝadon de...". Ankaŭ "toleri" eble estus bona vorto. La tono de via angla frazo ŝajne estas pli bone esprimita de tiuj vortoj ol de vortoj kiel "enui" aŭ "tediĝi".

Mi neniam antaŭe aŭdis "de x-i", kiam "x-i" estas infinitiva verbo. Tio al mi ŝajnas malĝusta, same kiel "I am bored of to eat sprouts everyday." Laŭ mi, "Mi enuas pro tio, ke ni/mi manĝas bruselbrasikojn ĉiutage." aŭ "Mi ne plu povas toleri (tion), ke ni/mi manĝas bruselbrasikojn ĉiutage." estus pli bona.

Comment: La demando estas en Esperanto, do la respondoj ankaŭ devas esti en Esperanto.

Comment: No, there isn't any rule about that. This is an English site that allows posts in Esperanto; it is not _Stack Overflow en español_.

Answer (score 7):

La plej facila solvo estas ***Min tedas...***

> *Min tedas manĝi burĝonbrasikojn ĉiutage.* I am bored of eating Brussels sprouts every day.

Vi ankaŭ povas diri *Min enuigas...* aŭ, laŭokaze, *laca*:

> *Mi sentas min laca de la senĉesaj diskutoj.* I am tired of the endless discussions.

Answer (score 5):

Mi kutimas diri: „Mi havas la faŭkon plena de brasiketoj”.

Answer (score 5):

Paŭl donis bonan frazon: „Mi havas la faŭkon plena de brasiketoj”.

Mi povus diri ankaŭ

- *Mi estas jam ŝtopita per brasikoj*

Unu esprimplena verbo, precipe kiam temas pri manĝado, estas *naŭzi*:

- Jam naŭzas min la ĉiamaj brasikoj!
- Ĉiutage manĝi brasikon jam naŭzas!

Ankaŭ laŭ PIV, *naŭzi* estas figurasence uzata por  *Kaŭzi senton de mallogo, abomeneto, tedego*.

Answer (score 3):

Eble "lacegi", "tediĝi" aŭ "enuegi" por la verbo, kaj vi povas alfiksi -aĉ- je la aĵon kiun vi ne ŝatas por pli fortigi la senton.

> Mi lacegas/tediĝas/enuegas de manĝi bruselbrasik(aĉ)ojn ĉiutage.